# Graph api version upgrade issue

Tags: php, facebook, symfony, facebook-graph-api, sdk

My facebook graph api version got upgraded from 2.2 to 2.3 automatically

and now I am getting the error as :

The www.facebook.com page isn’t working
www.facebook.com redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Symfony. Its the response you get from Api. [Check Here](https://github.com/restfb/restfb/issues/212) for github issues.

Comment: Where can i upgrade the version 2.2 to version 2.3?

Comment: [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading/) should help you.. But why to do want to upgrade to 2.3 when the latest version is 2.8?

Comment: I am using  $permissions = $this->facebook->api("/me/permissions"); in my code. But not using read_friendlists anywhere in the code. So I would like to know whether the version upgrade will affect the code or not?